# С++ Вывести строки с файла

Tags: c++, visual-c++

С++

В файле записаны 3 строки. Я знаю номер 3-ей строки "num".

Задача: вывести на экран из файла строку с номером num, строку num-1 и строку num-2.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

int main(){
ifstream file("file.txt");
string find,s; int k=0;

 cin >> find;  // ввод строки которую нужно найти в файле

  //узнаю номер этой  нужной строки в файле
    while (find != s) {
            getline(file, s);
            k++;
}

//запись из файла в массив, правильно ли я делаю?
 string L[100];
        int i = 0;
        while (getline(file, s)) {
                L[i]=s;
                i++;
    }
//вывожу нужные строки   
   for (int i = k - 2; i < k; i++) {
             cout << L[i];
    }

getch();
}

/*
Вывод должен быть таким:
1. выводится строка с файла с номером k-2
2. выводится строка с файла с номером k-1
3. Выводится строка введенная с клавиатуры (find) с номером k
*/
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86207/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И вот Вам вариант с вектором (с минимумом изменений):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
ifstream file("file.txt");
string find,s; int k=0;

 cin >> find;  // ввод строки которую нужно найти в файле

  //узнаю номер этой  нужной строки в файле
    while (find != s) {
            getline(file, s);
            k++;
}


file.seekg (0);
//запись из файла в массив, правильно ли я делаю?
//   string L[100];
vector <string> L;

        int i = 0;
        while (getline(file, s)) {
               // L[i]=s;
               L.push_back(s);
    }
//вывожу нужные строки   
   for (int i = k - 3; i < k; i++) {
             cout << L[i] << endl;
    }

getch();
}
```

Что напрашивается из улучшений?

1. Делать размер вектора сразу равным k строк.
2. Считывать в вектор только k строк, а не весь файл.